# A stack of words in C (Sentence Palindrome)

Tags: c, string, linked-list, stack, palindrome

I was given this problem and I needed to create a code for it. So we have a string which is inputed by the user and then the code needs to check if the sentence is a palindrome or not ( the symmetric words to the middle of the sentence should be the same. But we should implement this using a stacks. 
I am familiar with functions pop() and push() (even thought I have not used them below). What I have thought until now is that I take the strings and create a stack of words out of this strings and use that stack to check if the sentence is a palindrome. I am stuck now and I can't really think of anything else. Help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct stack
{
    char s[30];
    struct stack *next;
};

typedef struct stack STACK;

struct top
{
    int num;
    struct stack *top;
};

typedef struct top TOP;

void create_stack(TOP *s, char str[1000])
{
    char temp1[30];
    int i=0, j=0;

    STACK *temp;
    temp=(STACK*)malloc(1*sizeof(STACK));

    while(1)
    {
        if(str[i]!=' ' && str[i]!='\0')
        {
            temp1[j]=str[i];
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            temp1[j]='\0';
            strcpy(temp->s,temp1);
            printf("%s\n", temp->s);

            if(s->top==NULL)
            {
                s->top=temp;
                s->num=1;
            }
            else
            {
                temp->next=s->top;
                s->top=temp;
                s->num++;
            }
            j=0;
        }
        if(str[i]=='\0')
        {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

void move_cursor(STACK *cursor, int pos)
{
    while (pos!=0)
    {
        cursor=cursor->next;
        pos--;
    }
}

void compare(TOP *s)
{
    STACK *cursor1, *cursor2;
    cursor1=s->top;
    cursor2=s->top;
    int cursor_move1, cursor_move2, i=0, check=1;

    if(s->num%2==0)
    {
        cursor_move1=s->num/2;
        cursor_move2=(s->num/2)+1;

        while (i!=cursor_move1)
        {
            cursor1=s->top;
            cursor2=s->top;
            move_cursor(cursor1, i);
            move_cursor(cursor2, cursor_move2);

            if(strcmp(cursor1->s,cursor2->s)!=0)
            {
                check=0;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
                cursor_move2++;
            }
        }
    }

    if(check==0)
        printf("%d Neg", check);
    else
        printf("1Pos");
}

void display(TOP *top)
{
    STACK *cursor;
    cursor=top->top;

    while(cursor->next==NULL)
    {
        printf("%s pos\n ", cursor->s);

        cursor=cursor->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char input[1000];
    TOP top;
    top.num=0;
    top.top=NULL;

    fgets(input, 100, stdin);

    input[strlen(input)-1]='\0';

    create_stack(&top, input);

    printf("%d \n ", top.num);

    display(&top);
    printf("---------------------------------------------------------\n");
    compare(&top);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to create proper `stack` functions (e.g. `pop` and `push`) so that you would not need a `create_stack` fucntion that feeds the *whole* sentence into stack and thus you would have more flexibility. So then you split your string into words (take a look at [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function btw), push a half of them onto stack, (skip one word in case of add word count in sentence) and then in a loop: `pop` one from stack and compare to the next in sentence - if they don't match - terminate it's not a palindrome.

Comment: Are you stuck with the logic to solve this problem or with the implementation?

Comment: @AvantikaSaini I am stuck with the implementation. In the code above the stack is not created for some reasons (or it is not printing) and that is where I am stuck.

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych Thank you very much for this idea. Actually that is what I thought first but I decided to stick to this idea of creating a stack for every word. I will check the strtok function as well

Comment: Your definition of **'Sentence Palindrome'** is not the correct one. After filtering `' ', ',', ..., ';', '.'` all letters should be reverse-compared. Ex: **["Never a foot too far, even."](https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/icon/oddsends/palinsen.htm)**.

Answer (score 1):

There are different problems in your code. The biggest one that explains why you cannot feed the stack if that you only create one single element in the stack before starting the loop while you need obviously to allocate one element per word. Also you forget to initialize the `next` value of the top element to NULL. BTW in C you should never cast malloc.

The create_stack should become:

```
void create_stack(TOP *s, char str[1000])
{
    char temp1[30];
    int i=0, j=0;

    STACK *temp;
    temp=malloc(1*sizeof(STACK));
    temp->next = NULL;   // must be explicitely NULL for further use

    while(1)
    {
        if(str[i]!=' ' && str[i]!='\0')
        {
            temp1[j]=str[i];
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            temp1[j]='\0';
            strcpy(temp->s,temp1);
            printf("%s\n", temp->s);

            if(s->top==NULL)
            {
                s->top=temp;
                s->num=1;
            }
            else
            {
                temp->next=s->top;
                s->top=temp;
                s->num++;
            }
            j=0;
            temp=malloc(1*sizeof(STACK)); // time to allocate a new element
        }
        if(str[i]=='\0')
        {
            free(temp);  // last allocated has not been used
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

In display your loop test is plain wrong, it should be `while(cursor!=NULL)`

Once this is fixed you should use a debugger to understand while compare does not give the expected results. Anyway, my opinion is that instead of repeatedly move cursor, you should allocate an array of pointers to STACK element, feed it once with the content of your stack and use that array to to the comparisons directly between array elements, that is by index.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I was able to solve my question. I am posting the code below so if anybody needs it knows where to find it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct stack
{
char s[30];
struct stack *next;
};
typedef struct stack STACK;

struct top
{
int num;
STACK *top;
};
typedef struct top TOP;


void push(TOP *top, char str[30])
{
STACK *temp;
temp=malloc(1*sizeof(STACK));
temp->next = NULL;
strcpy(temp->s, str);

if(top->num==0)
{
     top->top=temp;
     top->num=1;
}
else
{
    temp->next=top->top;
    top->top=temp;
    top->num++;
}
}

void pop (TOP *top, char s[30])
{
STACK *temp;
temp=top->top;

    temp=temp->next;
    strcpy(s,top->top->s);
    free(top->top);
    top->top=temp;
    top->num--;
 }

 void create_stack(TOP *s, char str[1000])
 {
char temp1[30];
int i=0, j=0;
while(1)
{
    if(str[i]!=' ' && str[i]!='\0')
    {
        temp1[j]=str[i];
        j++;
    }
    else
    {
        temp1[j]='\0';
        push(s, temp1);
        j=0;
    }
    if(str[i]=='\0')
    {
        break;
    }
    i++;
   }
  }


void display(TOP *top)
   {
    STACK *cursor;
    cursor=top->top;

    while(cursor!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n ", cursor->s);

        cursor=cursor->next;
    }
 }

 void compare(TOP *top, char *s)
 {
char s2[1000];
s2[0]='\0';
char ret[30];
int len;


pop(top,ret);
strcpy(s2, ret);

while(top->top!=NULL)
{
    len=strlen(s2);
    s2[len]=' ';
    s2[len+1]='\0';
    ret[0]='\0';
    pop(top,ret);
    strcat(s2, ret);
}

 if(strcmp(s, s2)==0)
     printf("The sentence is palindromic by words!\n");

 else
    printf("The sentence is not palindromic by words!\n");

}

int main()
{
char input[1000];
TOP top;
top.num=0;
top.top=NULL;

while(1)
{
fgets(input, 100, stdin);

input[strlen(input)-1]='\0';

if(strcmp(input, "exit")==0)
    break;

    create_stack(&top, input);


    compare(&top, input);


 }



    return 0;
}
```

Try it on input "cats like dogs and dogs like cats"